# Declare a class in java

Tags: java, oop

Im a beginner. I have a issue about class in java. So 
I have two class Father and class Son extends class Father

```
class Father
{
   Father(){};
   public void SayHi()
   {
       System.out.println("Hello world");
   }
}
class Son extends Father
{
   Son(){}
   public void SayHiToo()
   {
       System.out.println("Hello world, too!");
   }

}
class DO
{
    public static void  main(String[] args)
    {
          Father c1 = new Father();     //(1)
          Son c2 = new Son();           //(2)
          Father c3 = new Son();        //(3)
    }
}
```

My question is about: I know that (1),(2) mean c1 can only use functions in class Father and c2 can use functions in class Son and Father
But if I declare c3 like this, what is it mean? 
Thanks very much

Comment: it means you have `Father` as type of your reference c3, and you can use methods from `Father` class only

Comment: Later, you will learn about polymorphism: `Son` may override methods of `Father`, so if you call a method of `Father` via `c3` is may behave differently.

Comment: The relationship between `Son` and `Father` shouldn't be "is a". `Son` is not a `Father`

Comment: `c1` and `c3` can only receive `Father` methods (even though `c3` is actually a son). `c2` can receive `Father` or `Son` methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will become much more clear if you give your classes better names.

An important thing to remember is: inheritance means *specialization*: a subclass **is a** special kind of its superclass.

Now you see why `class Father` and `class Son extends Father` are really wrong: a `Son` is **not** a (special kind of) `Father`.

Instead of `Father` and `Son`, let's use `Animal` and `Cat`:

```
class Animal {
    public void makeSound() {
        System.out.println("Beep!");
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void makeSound() {
        System.out.println("Miaow!");
    }
}
```

Now it's easier to understand what these mean:

```
Animal c1 = new Animal(); // 1
Cat c2 = new Cat();       // 2
Animal c3 = new Cat();    // 3

Cat c4 = new Animal();    // 4 WRONG!
```

A `Cat` **is an** `Animal`, so in (3) it is allowed to assign a `Cat` object to a variable of type `Animal` - `Cat` is guaranteed to have all methods that are available on `Animal`. So, any method you could call on `c3` exists in the object that `c3` refers to.

The other way around, assigning an `Animal` to a variable of type `Cat` as in (4), is not allowed, since class `Cat` might have extra methods that you can't call on an `Animal` object. If (4) was allowed, you could try to call those methods, which should not be possible.

Answer (score 2):

It's like instanciating a Son that will act like a Father!

I would suggest you reading about java polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

With `Father c3 = new Son();`, the `c3` can only use the methods of `Father`, but as it's a `Son` , you can cast it as a `Son` to use also `Son's` method

```
Father c3 = new Son();
c3.SayHi();
Son sc3 = (Son) c3;
sc3.SayHiToo();
```

---

But be careful at your model : is a `Son` a type of `Father` ? No.

For example :

- a `Car` is a `Vehicule`
- a `Smartphone` is a `Phone`

Answer (score 0):

A Father reference can always refer to a Son instance, because Son IS-A Father. What makes that supertype reference to a subtype instance possible is that the subtype is guaranteed to be able to do everything the supertype can do. Whether the Son instance overrides the inherited methods of Father or simply inherits them, anyone with an Father reference to a Son instance is free to call all accessible Father methods. For that reason, an overriding method must fulfill the contract of the superclass.